# Dropping groups from pandas groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large groupby dataframe and a smaller list of ids that are a subset of that data frame.  The ids are the names of the groups.  I would like to drop all groups that are not present in the list of ids.

I tried this:

```
for name, group in groups_copy:
    if name in ids:
        print "¯\_(ツ)_/¯"
    else:
        groups_copy.drop(groups_copy.loc[name])
```

and got this error: `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'drop' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

Thoughts on the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to filter it out before you groupby.

`df = df[df['groupby_column'].isin(ids)]`

Comment: Yea, was wondering if there was a different way because the list of ids is built off of summary data that I get from the groupby

Comment: Hm. If you can look at each group and compute (group-by-group) whether you want to keep it, you can use `df.groupby('col').filter`. Otherwise you just have to groupby first to get the summary data, then filter, then groupby again.